# How structure/organize a google drive api file download flow as a celery task?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, celery

Thanks for reading, I'm not asking for code snippets, but just more an overall architectural explanation of how the below could be achieved, ideally with best practices, would be very appreciated.

I have a situation where I allow users to upload files from their google drive that is later processed (essentially read) by a celery task. The current flow just authenticates the user through oauth2 and gets the file ID for the file. Then I just save a URL in the form of `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=${file.id}` into the database which is later read by the celery task and using the `requests` library, downloaded and read.

This works fine for unrestricted (publicly shared) files but when the files are set to have some restrictions (shared only to a group, to specific users, etc), it returns request forbidden 403s.

I'm currently following https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads guide and got a snippet working that downloads a restricted file. Essentially, it does a separate oauth2 flow initiated by the server and writes a `token.pickle` file that is later read to authenticate the file download request and voila, it succeeds in downloading.

The problem is tying the two flows together, specifically, how would / should I set this up so that the celery task is able to download the file sometime after oauth2 was completed?

I'm thinking I'd create the token.pickle file for a user somewhere that celery can read from and do the downloading. I'm not sure if there are any gotchas or security concerns with this.

Altogether, I'm using AWS, so I could put a `token-for-user-123.pickle` file in S3 from the app, save the bucket name to a DB record, and have the celery task query for that and read from that location? I suppose that would work, but I'm not sure of the security repercussions and even less sure of what would happen when the tokens expire, whenever that is. Files only process on a separate request, so it could happen seconds after the users authenticate and select a file or never.

One last thing, if there were a google URL I could hit with the tokens passed in in the form of something like `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=${file.id}&token={token}&whatever-else={whatever-else}` that can download restricted files, that would be amazing!

Thank you!

Comment: About `This works fine for unrestricted files but when the files are set to have some restrictions, it returns request forbidden 403s.`, in your case, the file you want to download is publicly shared?

Comment: Not always. Sometimes the files are publicly shared, other times are shared to google groups (generally companies) with the link, other times they are restricted to specific people or no one.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information.